# IntelliSense shows different sets of functions for CComPtr<T> depending on whether I use dot or arrow operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl

In my code I have

```
CComPtr<SomeInterface> object;
```

When I use `object.` IntelliSense shows a set of available functions. And when I use `object->` it shows me another set of available functions. Why are those function sets different?

Comment: Could you take time to express your question in an understandable manner?!

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Newbie question decoder to the rescue!

Answer (score 4):

With such declaration:

```
CComPtr<T> object;
```

using dot you access members of `CComPtr` class, for example, `CComPtr.Detach()` method:

```
*doublePointerToT = object.Detach(); // pass ownership - calls CComPtr<T>::Detach()
```

and using arrow you gain the stored `T*` pointer and then arrow operator is applied to `T*` retrieved and so you see members of `T`:

```
 object->QueryInterface( ... ); //calls T::QueryInterface()
```

So with dot you see member functions of `CComPtr` class and with arrow you see functions of `T` class.

Comment: In other words, operator->() is overloaded for CComPtr<T>.